# ExtJS 4.2.0 Nested modal windows issue

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a tree in a modal window, when I select tree node I want to show another modal window to confirm action, but due to bug in ExtJS 4.2.0 (it seems to be fixed in ExtJS 4.2.1) second modal window displayed under first modal window (z-index-wise).

Check this [simple fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1tfl).

Any idea how I can fix this issue for 4.2.0?